# Export to Excel with Toad Automation Designer

Tags: excel, toad

I am using the Toad Automation Designer to export data of table to Excel. 
Unfortunately my table contains more then 65000 rows (100k) and every single Excel file
can only contain 65k entries.

My workaround was to write two SQL statements to create two Excel files

```
select * from my_table offset 0 rows FETCH NEXT 65000 ROWS ONLY

select * from my_table offset 64999 rows
```

That is ok for the moment but I am looking for a more dynamic way to export the whole
table into several Excel files without writing multiple SQL statement because in future
I will have maybe 300k entries in my database table.

So I am looking for a possibility to write something like a little script in the 
Automation Designer or something similar.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can't you build some sort of loop. Devide the total amount of rows by 65000, and have a loop starting at 0 untill the value of your division. Then have a statement that is your loop value multiplying by 64999

Comment: @Luuklag and how do I have to implement this within the Toad Automation Designer?

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue, the excel tag brought me here. However this clearly is not an excel issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had similar issue: Toad .xls download populates one tab (64K rows). Only difference is that my Toad (11) would then populate another tab with residual data (the next 64K rows), then another tab and so on until all data was downloaded... it sometimes took many tabs.

I changed the download file type to .xlsx and then all the data downloaded to one tab.

safety tip: After download, Excel will have no problem opening the downloaded xlsx - but I have to open/save/close the downloaded .xlsx in Excel prior to using an ms access import spec. (else access' import spec complains the file's unreadable).